# My discord.js cooldown script doesn't execute properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have been in this situation for a couple of weeks and never found a way to solve it. The problem is, I made a cooldown script for my Discord bot but it seems that the entire cooldown script doesn't do what it has been instructed.

Here's the entire code:

```
const { Events, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const cooldowns = new Collection();

module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
            console.log('Not a chat input command, skipping.');
            return;
        }

        const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!command) {
            console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
            return;
        }

        const now = Date.now();
        const commandCooldowns = cooldowns.get(command.data.name) || new Collection();
        const defaultCooldownDuration = 3;
        const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown ?? defaultCooldownDuration) * 1000;

        if (commandCooldowns.has(interaction.user.id)) {
            const expirationTime = commandCooldowns.get(interaction.user.id) + cooldownAmount;

            if (now < expirationTime) {
                const expiredTimestamp = Math.round(expirationTime / 1000);
                return interaction.reply({ content: `Please wait, you are on a cooldown for \`${command.data.name}\`. You can use it again <t:${expiredTimestamp}:R>.`, ephemeral: true });
            }
        }

        commandCooldowns.set(interaction.user.id, now);

        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error executing ${interaction.commandName}`);
            console.error(error);
        }
    },
};
```

Here's the cooldown script:

```
        const now = Date.now();
        const commandCooldowns = cooldowns.get(command.data.name) || new Collection();
        const defaultCooldownDuration = 3;
        const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown ?? defaultCooldownDuration) * 1000;

        if (commandCooldowns.has(interaction.user.id)) {
            const expirationTime = commandCooldowns.get(interaction.user.id) + cooldownAmount;

            if (now < expirationTime) {
                const expiredTimestamp = Math.round(expirationTime / 1000);
                return interaction.reply({ content: `Please wait, you are on a cooldown for \`${command.data.name}\`. You can use it again <t:${expiredTimestamp}:R>.`, ephemeral: true });
            }
        }

        commandCooldowns.set(interaction.user.id, now);
```

Take note that this is made in interaction handler.

Comment: What has it been instructed to do? You haven't provided what's the problem or what's the intended behavior, you just dumped a bunch of code and said it doesn't do what I want it to do.